# Como destruir todas as sessões de um usuário, salvo a sessão corrente?

Tags: laravel

Como posso de uma única vez efetuar logout de todas as demais sessões de um usuário, preservando somente a sessão corrente?

Tenho como objetivo aplicar este comportamento ao redefinir a senha do usuário. Por padrão o Laravel mantem as sessões antigas validas mesmo após o usuário alterar sua senha, *isso pode ser um problema* caso o objetivo do usuário seja impedir acessos de terceiros que por ventura tenham "adquirido" sua senha.

Obs: estou utilizando o Laravel 5.6

Comment: Só se você configurar as Sessions para serem armazenadas no banco

Comment: A sessão é armazenada no computador da pessoa. Logo você precisaria desenvolver algo com banco de dados

Comment: Observação: Não existe problema em múltiplas máquinas acessarem um mesmo login. O problema mesmo é manter uma pessoa obter a senha da outra. Por isso existe email. No qual você pode notificar o usuário quando uma máquina diferente acessar sua conta.

Comment: @Sveen o objetivo não é notificar o acesso vindo de outra máquina. Meu objetivo é somente desligar todas as sessões quando a senha for alterada, com excessão da session corrente.